# Tried to register widget with id==valores0 but that id is already registered

Tags: javascript, loops, dojo, slider

i get this error, and i don't know how can be solved. I read [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222517/error-tried-to-register-widget-with-id-grid1but-that-id-is-already-registered) before.

**EDIT:1**

index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {   
    $("#customForm").submit(function() {
        var formdata = $("#customForm").serializeArray();

        $.ajax({
            url: "sent.php",
            type: "post",
            dataType: "json",
            data: formdata,
            success: function(data) {
                switch (data.livre) {
                case 'tags':
                    $("#msgbox2").fadeTo(200, 0.1, function() {
                        $(this).html('Empty tags').fadeTo(900, 1);
                    });
                    break;

                default:
                    $("#msgbox2").fadeTo(200, 0.1, function() {
                        $(this).html('Update').fadeTo(900, 1, function() {
                            $('#conteudo').load('dojo/test_Slider.php');   
                        });
                    });
                    break;
                }
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

test_slider.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var slider = [];

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

    slider[i] = (

    function(i) {

        return function() {

            var node = dojo.byId("input"+[i]);
            var n = dojo.byId("valores"+[i]);

            var rulesNode = document.createElement('div'+[i]);
            node.appendChild(rulesNode);

            var sliderRules = new dijit.form.HorizontalRule({
                count:11,
                style:{height:"4px"}
            },rulesNode);

            var labels = new dijit.form.HorizontalRuleLabels({
                style:{height:"1em",fontSize:"75%"},
            },n);

            var theSlider = new dijit.form.HorizontalSlider({
                value:5,
                onChange: function(){
                    console.log(arguments);
                },
                name:"input"+[i],
                onChange:function(val){ dojo.byId('value'+[i]).value = dojo.number.format(1/val,{places:4})},
                style:{height:"165px"},
                minimum:1,
                maximum:9,
                   }
            },node);

            theSlider.startup();
                sliderRules.startup();
        }

    })(i);
    dojo.addOnLoad(slider[i]);
}

</script>
```

Problem: First click in submit btn all works well, 5 sliders are imported. Second click, an update is supposed, but i get this message:

```
Tried to register widget with id==valores0 but that id is already registered
```

**[Demo video]**[2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=paj_TUu7yO4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to add on to @missingo's answer and @Kevin's comment. You could walk through the existing dijits by looking in the registry:

```
var i = i || 0; // Cache this at the end of your loop
dijit.registry.map(function (widget) {
    if (+widget.id.replace(/^[^\d]+/, '') <  i) {
        widget.destroyRecursive();
    }
});
/*
    Your loop fixed as described in missingno's answer.
*/
```

Comment: this answers works for me when the if condition is removed. Can you explain the condition please?

Comment: This is a six year old answer. I doubt the registry is still laid out the same way. The idea was to remove the older widget, but I'm not touching dojo much these days, so don't have connect on the new versions.

Answer (score 1):

You fell in the age-old trap of making function closures inside a for loop. By the time addOnLoad fires and the sliders are created, `i` will be equal to 2 and both sliders will try to use the same DOM nodes (something that is not allowed).

You need to make sure that you give a fresh copy of `i` for everyone. The following is a quick fix:

```
for(i=0; i<2; i++){
    (function(i){

        slider[i] = ...

        //everything inside here remains the same
        //except that they now use their own i from the wrapper function
        //instead of sharing the i from outside.
    }(i));
}
```

Comment: missingno, what you suggest solves the issue. But if i have a .load (dojo.php) and for each time that i submit a form, i will reload the dojo content, i get again a problem with a Tried to register id... Do you understand what i mean ? each time that i call the dojo i have x different IDS. But for each load the group of ids are the same.

Comment: I know php that much. What do you mean by call the dojo and why would the ids being the same matter to you?

Comment: the problem is the following: i have a button that when pressed import this dojo content to another file. The point, is that button can be pressed many times, and it is supposed refresh the content. After a second click in that button, i get again: Tried to register widget with id==input0 but that id is already registered.

Comment: One not so savory way to fix this is to look up and destroy all the nodes you need to use before you make the ajax call.  

You can either manually look up all these ids(be sure to use dijit.byId!!!) with another loop before the ajax call and call .destroy() on each, or you can push all your created dijits (HorizontalRule, HorizontalRuleLabels, HorizontalSlider) into an array for easy destruction.

Answer (score 1):

Dijit stores all active widgets in the dijit.registry, and uses id's as unique qualifiers. You can't create dijits with same id.

Need to clean dojo.registry before create a new slider dijits. Add this code before declare dijit on test_slider.php

```
dijit.registry["input"+ [i]].destroyRecursive();
```

Comment: I added your code after return function() { and i get this error: >>> dijit.registry["input" + i] is undefined (13 out of range 4). Did you mean dijit.registry("input"+ [i]).destroyRecursive() ? well in this case i get dijit.registry is not a function (13 out of range 4)

Comment: Sorry I mistyped my response you need to put [i]. The second error message is why dijit.registry  is an array and not a function.    dijit.registry["input"+ [i]].destroyRecursive();

Comment: 'input' + [i] is will invoke [i].toString() wich will return i, this is redundant. Did you mean 'input['+i+']' ?

Answer (score 0):

can you assign any number ID like ID generated by 10 digit random number or something with datetime combination so id will never be same.

Comment: I can't use an unique ID. I need the same id names between JS and html