# Another Tried to register widget with id on dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a problem: I'm opening a template based view from a controller and I am getting this error. 
What can be the cause of this error?

Controller:

```
define([ 
    "dojo/_base/declare", "dojo/_base/lang", 

    "models/RestStorage", 
    "views/userPage/UserPage" 
], function (declare, lang, RestStorage, UserPage) { 
    return declare(null, { 
        systemUser:"", 

        constructor:function (options) { 
            lang.mixin(this, options); 
            this.model = new RestStorage(); 
        }, 
        init:function () { 
            this.view = new UserPage({model:this.model}, "container"); 
        } 
    }); 
});
```

View:

```
define([ 
    "dojo/_base/declare", "dojo/_base/lang", "dojo/Evented", 

    "dijit/_WidgetBase", "dijit/_TemplatedMixin", "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin", "dojo/text!./user-page.html", 

    "dojox/mvc/Group", "dojox/mvc/Repeat", "dojox/mvc/Output" , "dijit/form/Button" 
], function (declare, lang, Evented, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin, template) { 
        return declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin, Evented], { 
            templateString:template, 
            model:null, 

            constructor:function (options) { 
                lang.mixin(this, options); 
            } 
       }); 
    } 
);
```

And template:

```
<section id="userPage">
    <header id="userPageHeader">
    </header>
    <section id="userPageContent">
        <p data-dojo-type="dojox/mvc/Group" data-dojo-props="ref: this.model">
            Current count: <br/>
            Max count: 
        </p>
    </section>
    <footer id="userPageFooter">
    </footer>
</section>
```

Update:
this is my index.html and app.js:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>MNSolution</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/js/lib/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" media="screen"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/main.css"/>
    <script>
        var dojoConfig = {
            async:true,
            baseUrl:"resources/js/",
            packages:[
                {name:"dojo", location:"lib/dojo" },
                {name:"dijit", location:"lib/dijit" },
                {name:"dojox", location:"lib/dojox" },
                {name:"app", location:"app", main:"app" },
                {name:"controllers", location:"app/controllers"},
                {name:"views", location:"app/views"},
                {name:"models", location:"app/models"}
            ],
            has:{
                "dojo-debug-messages":true
            },
            isDebug:true,
            parseOnLoad:true,
            deps:[ "dojo/parser", "app/app" ]
        }
    </script>
    <script src="resources/js/lib/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
    <script>
        require(["dojo/parser", "app/app"], function (parser, App) {
            parser.parse();
            var application = new App();

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body class="claro">
<div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>

define([
//    Base modules
    "dojo/_base/declare", "dojo/_base/lang",
//    login and user page controllers
    "controllers/LoginController", "controllers/UserPageController",
//    ready!
    "dojo/ready"
], function (declare, lang, LoginController, UserPageController) {
    return declare("app", null, {
        loginController:null,
        userPageController:null,

        constructor:function () {
            this.loginController = new LoginController();

            if (!this._checkAuth()) {
                this.loginController.init();
                this.loginController.on("loginSuccess", lang.hitch(this, function () {
                    this._loginSuccess();
                }));
            } else {
                this._loginSuccess();
            }
        },
        _checkAuth:function () {
//TODO check auth
            return true;
        },
        _loginSuccess:function () {
            this.userPageController = new UserPageController({});
            this.userPageController.init();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you include some more details? Like what error you're getting.

Comment: What version of dojo? What does your HTML look like?

Comment: Here is more details: only this controller has been initialized and there is no any more components with this id. Here is full text of error message: "Tried to register widget with id==dojox_mvc_Group_0 but that id is already registered".

Comment: @Dancrumb, I added my index.html in post. And dojo version is 1.8.

Comment: you can try widget.destroyRecursive(); related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735000/tried-to-register-widget-with-id-valores0-but-that-id-is-already-registered

Comment: @loops, if I had a windget, I'll would use a destroyRecursive() method, but application rase an exception on this line: 'this.view = new UserPage({model:this.model}, "container");'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice that you have some *id* attributes set in your template.  It's normally bad form to do this as it can result in duplicate ids when you use a widget more than once on a page.  This can result in the duplicate id error you describe in the title.

If you are using the ids for css-styling then you can probably work around this with class attributes.  If they are for referencing within your code, use *data-dojo-attach-point*.

**data-dojo-attach-point:** This will assign the dom node it is attached to, to a property within the object parsing the template. (Note: you are using *dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin*, if the node is a widget to be parsed the property will be assigned to the widget rather than it's dom node).

eg:

```
<section data-dojo-attach-point="userPage">
    <header data-dojo-attach-point="userPageHeader">
    </header>
    <section data-dojo-attach-point="userPageContent">
        <p data-dojo-type="dojox/mvc/Group" data-dojo-props="ref: this.model">
            Current count: <br/>
            Max count: 
        </p>
    </section>
    <footer data-dojo-attach-point="userPageFooter">
    </footer>
</section>
```

This will assign the outer **<section>** node to **this.userPage** within the widget, **this.userPageHeader** will reference the **<header>**, ...etc.